# How do I refresh Controls bound to a DataSource in C# User Control

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am slightly confused in my understanding of DataSources in Winforms, and was hoping somebody might be able to clear something up for me.

I have one control, lets call it Host, and I have another one, called Client.

"Host" contains multiple instances of "Client"

Client displays four main variables, in labels at the moment, which are bound to a BindingSource per control.

I am updating these BindingSources from the Host control however, using database values retrieved using LINQ.

When I update the BindingSource from the "Host" control, the values to not update in the "Client" controls as I expected they would.

Can anyone give me a quick explanation of any methods I need to call in order to make sure that the labels refresh with latest data whenever the BindingSource is changed?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

You must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

> The INotifyPropertyChanged interface is used to notify clients, typically binding clients, that a property value has changed.

#### Sample

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    private string myProperty;
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return this.myProperty;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.myProperty)
            {
                this.myProperty = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

Comment: Implement it where? On my "Client" control?

Comment: On which class? Sorry I am a bit confused.

Comment: How is the DataSource defined ? Do you have a list of something ?

Comment: Yes, it is a List of one of my Linq Generated Classes.